# user format to ugettext

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

How use foramt to ugettext?

```
# is not valid code
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def index(req):
    return _('Hello world {}').format('Users')
```

ore use (сreate more duplicate):

```
_('Hello world {}'.format('Users'))
```

Comment: Well it depends on whether you want the string `Users` to be translated or not

Comment: @Sayse Why? String: "Hello world Users" return to function.

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear about my previous comment - or what you meant in your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first will mark "'Hello world {}'" as the translatable string and will apply `format('Users')` to the (eventually translated) string. IOW in your .po files you'll have 'Hello world {}'

The second will first apply `format('Users')` to 'Hello world {}', so the translatable string (what you'll get in your .po files) will be 'Hello world Users' - actually it's exactly the same as if you'd pass the literal "Hello world Users" string to `ugettext`.

Since you're asking about the use of `format()` for translations I assume you want the first (and you're actually using some variable as argument instead of the literal string "Users").

Actually the best practice would be to use keyword args (ie `_('Hello world {users}').format(users=somevarhere)`) so the translator have some hint about what the placeholder stands for and, in the case of a string with multiple placeholders, can reorder them according the target language.